# extract data from a json file in python

Tags: python, json

I have been try to find the best way to search a particular value and extract the data. I am new and hope i have worded this correctly.

```
    {"family": {
    "name": "Mary",
    "age": "32",
    "sex": "female",
    "kids": [
      {
        "name": "jim",
        "age": "10",
        "sex": "male",
        "dob_year": "2007",
        "ssn": "123-23-1234"
      },
      {
        "name": "jill",
        "age": "6",
        "sex": "female",
        "dob_year": "2011",
        "ssn": "123-23-1235"
      }]}}
```

if i needed to search "ssn" containing "1234" and return the "name" "jim" what would be the best way to go about achieving this?

Comment: depends on the file size, dict keys are dynamically changed or not .etc; simply json.loads to get the dict and go on comparing later on? Or could you please paste your code snippet here?

Answer (score 3):

Actually question was about extracting from **file**

So here you are:

```
import json

with open('data.json') as json_file:
    data = json.load(json_file)
    for kid in data['family']['kids']:
        if '1234' in kid['ssn']:
            print(kid['name'])
```

Additional reading: https://stackabuse.com/reading-and-writing-json-to-a-file-in-python/

Answer (score 2):

You can first iterate kids and apply condition

```
import json
js = '''your json text data'''
j = json.loads(js)

for items in j['family']['kids']:
    if '1234' in items['ssn']:
        print(items['name'])
```

Output

```
'jim'
```

Comment: This way worked perfect, how would I do it if i had multiple kids with "1234" and wanted the list of names with the sex?

Answer (score 0):

use json package like below

```
ans =     '{"family": {
    "name": "Mary",
    "age": "32",
    "sex": "female",
    "kids": [
      {
        "name": "jim",
        "age": "10",
        "sex": "male",
        "dob_year": "2007",
        "ssn": "123-23-1234"
      },
      {
        "name": "jill",
        "age": "6",
        "sex": "female",
        "dob_year": "2011",
        "ssn": "123-23-1235"
      }]}}'
temp = json.loads(ans)
for kid in  temp['family']['kids']:
     print kid['name'],kid['ssn']
```

hope this is what you look for .

Answer (score 0):

say you load your json text into js variable. `kn = next((sj['name'] for sj in js['family']['kids'] if ('1234' in sj['ssn'])), None)`

kn will give you the name if criteria found, otherwise it will be None. And of course you can change the condition into variable. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

I'd rather like to provide a common method handling this case, the **until** method which is based on python functional programming, using this, you can find your target(provide a default value if not found), and you can decouple your filter criteria and candidates easily.

```
json_str = """
{"family": {
    "name": "Mary",
    "age": "32",
    "sex": "female",
    "kids": [
      {
        "name": "jim",
        "age": "10",
        "sex": "male",
        "dob_year": "2007",
        "ssn": "123-23-1234"
      },
      {
        "name": "jill",
        "age": "6",
        "sex": "female",
        "dob_year": "2011",
        "ssn": "123-23-1235"
      }]}}
"""
```

load the data to a python dict object

```
import json
data = json.loads(json_str)
```

Now here's the until part:

```
def until(terminate, iterator, default=None):
    try:
        i = next(iterator)
        if terminate(i):
            return i
        return until(terminate, iterator, default)
    except StopIteration:
        return default


ssn_target = '1234'

target_kid = until(lambda kid: ssn_target in kid['ssn'], iter(data['family']['kids']))

if target_kid is not None:
    print(target_kid['name'])
else:
    print('Opps! not found')
```

**Note that:**

Python has a rather small limit to how many recursive calls can be made (typically ~1000), so the iterable list shouldn't be tooo long.